# Swift compilation error when using different function names x(cell:) and x(withCell:)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

function x is written with different parameter Name

```
func x(cell:Int)  { }      
func x(onCell:Int){ }//will Not give compile time error because it treats as different name    
func x(withCell:Int){}//For this Line Compile time error is coming why??
```

> //: Method 'x(withCell:)' with Objective-C selector 'xWithCell:'
>   conflicts with method 'x(cell:)' with the same Objective-C selector

Comment: This is neither Objective-C nor Swift.

Comment: This is a valid question in swift and not a duplicate of other question. People are quick to judge and close it. It is really tough for a new person to ask question in SO. His title was wrong and that caused all confusion but if you read question it is about overloading in swift.

Comment: @Mayur, the issue is that in ObjC swift functions `x(cell:)` and `x(withCell:)` are converted to `xWithCell:`. That is why it doesn't allow that. Other function you wrote is converted to `xOnCell:` which is a different method compared to this. This has nothing to do with overloading in ObjC as it is not overloading.

Comment: Please reopen the question. The question tagged as duplicate and this question has nothing in common. This is not method overloading and this question is about how swift converts its functions to ObjC, not about how ObjC does overloading.

Comment: @adev I guess you might be right.I Can't re-Open this,I don't have priveldge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

The issue is that in ObjC swift functions `x(cell:)` and `x(withCell:)` are converted to `xWithCell:`. That is why it doesn't allow that. Other function you wrote is converted to `xOnCell:` which is a different method compared to this. This has nothing to do with overloading in ObjC as it doesn't fall into overloading. It is just a different function signature. Hope that helps.